# Terraform InvalidParameterCombination with AWS Microsoft SQL

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-rds

Having issues when trying to create an AWS RDS instance with terraform, I have gone through the documentation in AWS and Terraform and I just cannot see why this would be an invalid combination, I'm trying to create a free tier DB for testing:

```
resource "aws_db_instance" "rds-mssql" {
  allocated_storage   = 20
  engine              = "sqlserver-ee" 
  engine_version      = "14.00.3356.20.v1"
  instance_class      = "db.t2.micro"
  name                = "mydbtest"
  username            = "usernameGoesHere"
  password            = "passwordGoesHere"
  license_model       = "license-included"
}
```

Getting the following error:

```
Error: Error creating DB Instance: InvalidParameterCombination: RDS does not support creating a DB instance with the following combination: DBInstanceClass=db.t2.micro, Engine=sqlserver-ee, EngineVersion=14.00.3356.20.v1, LicenseModel=license-included. For supported combinations of instance class and database engine version, see the documentation
```

I have followed documentation from here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/APIReference/API_CreateDBInstance.html

Also I have created manually from the AWS console a DB with those specs with no problem

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sqlserver-ee` is for **Enterprise Edition** which [does not support](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_SQLServer.html#SQLServer.Concepts.General.InstanceClasses) t2.micro. I guess you want `sqlserver-ex` (express edition).

Comment: Thanks for that once Marcin, silly mistake from me I was considering ee as (express edition)